# Parse Dashboard isn't accessible through domain name

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm a newbie developer and I want to deploy Parse Server on my own Ubuntu 20.4 server. I couldn't find an updated tutorial however

after follow [Installing Parse Server on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/tutorials/install-parse-server/) I finally managed to install and run Parse Server and Parse Dashboard, but this dashboard can only be accessed via an IP address like `122.22.22.22:4040` I have a domain name with CloudFlare DNS, which is connected to my server ip, but my domain only displays default NGINX html, and after opening ParseDashboard url, I received a 404 error."

here is my NGINX configuration file located in :

```
  sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
    server_name example www.example.com; 
         
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
     location /login {
     proxy_pass http://88.88.88.88:4040/login;
  }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
   
    server_name your.domain.com; 
         
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
    }
   
}
```